# Downloaded requests HTML different from Chrome's Devtools

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to follow along with some code in Chapter 11 of Automate the Boring Stuff with Python. One of the programs lucky.py, however, doesn't seem to work for me.
The program is supposed to get the Google search page for a particular topic using the requests module and then open the first 5 search results in different tabs.
When I look at Chrome's Devtools for a search page, it's pretty clear to me that every search result link (`<a>` tag) is within a div with a class 'r'. However, when I request the page, send the downloaded HTML to a .txt file and look through it, the HTML I find that codes for the search result link is completely different. Why are they different? Isn't the entire purpose of devtools to be a way to quickly check out the HTML for a particular element in a webpage without having to go through the entire source code?

Previously, I was trying `soup.select('.r a')` work because every search page had search result links in a div with class 'r'. That didn't work. The list returned was always empty. So to troubleshoot, I sent the requested page to a file and found where the links were. The links in the text file all lead to error 404s. I don't know what's happening.

Devtools code:

```
<div class="r">
<a href="https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/" ping="/urlsa=t&amp;source=web&amp;rct=j&amp;url=https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjj1vTx3NXiAhVPinAKHersDyoQFjAAegQIAhAB"><h3 class="LC20lb">Beautiful Soup Documentation — Beautiful Soup 4.4.0 documentation</h3><br><div class="TbwUpd"><cite class="iUh30">https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/</cite>
```

Now this is where I found the link in the requested page:

```
<div class="jfp3ef"> 
<a href="/urlq=https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjMjPST2tXiAhU463MBHWjMA0UQFjAAegQIChAB&amp;usg=AOvVaw05aFh5uUJ_Z2oREgu8fzfA">
```

This is the code I used to get the page:

```
res = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + ' '.join(['beautiful', 'soup'])
bs = open('soup.txt', 'wb')
for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
    bs.write(chunk)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost certainly need to turn off javascript to be able to see the elements as your program does. https://github.com/maximelebreton/quick-javascript-switcher You can find it on the chrome extensions/addons page. This will allow you to turn off javascript on a page. You will notice looking at it after this that the page will look different and your links will most likely be in different elements/classes.

You should be able to find the correct way to target the elements with your devtools after that.

The links may not be working because of some cookie put in by google perhaps? However the fact that you got a list with no links in it makes me think you didn't get the correct css selector.

Comment: It worked! I cannot describe how beyond thankful I am for your help. I've been scratching my head over this for an entire day now. One thing that I wanted to ask, why is the JS affecting the code in devtools?

Comment: The devtools just show what the html document looks like now. So if they use javascript to manipulate the dom then the devtools show you the manipulated dom. The python scraper however does not run javascript so those manipulations do not happen. Thus the program is seeing a different dom than you are when you visit the page unless you turn off js. Glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's the most common question on the StackOverFlow that is being asked 200+ times in `[requests]` and `[bs4]` tags, and pretty much every solution lies down to simply adding `user-agent`.

It's because you haven't specified `user-agent`. [`User-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/User_agent) is needed to act as a "real" user visit when the bot or browser sends a fake user-agent string to announce themselves as a different client.

When no `user-agent` is being passed to request `headers` while using `requests` library, it defaults to [python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) and Google understands that it's a bot/script, then it blocks a request (or whatever it does) and you receive a different HTML (with some sort of an error) with different `CSS` selectors. That's why the response you get does not contain some `CSS` selectors as you might expect.

Check [what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent). [List of `user-agents`](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/).

*Note: Adding `user-agent` doesn't mean that it will fix the problem and you still can get a 429 (or different) error, even when rotating `user-agents`.*

Pass `user-agent`:

```py
headers = {
    'User-agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582'
}

requests.get('URL', headers=headers)
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference is that you don't have to spend time trying to bypass blocks from Google or other search engines or figuring out why certain things don't work as they should. Instead, you need to focus on the data you want to extract. Check out the [playground](https://serpapi.com/playground).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.